# exec('history') return empty

Tags: node.js, bash

I am trying to grab history within nodejs.

This is what I use:

```
var p = require('child_process');
p.exec('history', (e,d)=>{console.log('history:', d);})
```

The output is just

```
history:
```

Why is it empty? And how to get the full bash history of the current user?

Thanks

Comment: `exec()` starts a new shell. It has no history. Starting a new child process is no way to get the history of the parent process.

Comment: It's *possible* for the shell to have history, if it loads it from a history file, but it does appear that in this case the shell does *not*.

Comment: If it magically loads it from a file that the parent shell magically updated just beforehand so as to magically contain its history. Not proven.